# how to get the current view contents only in angularjs controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-templates, angularjs-material

I'm dealing with md-tabs-wrapper it gives the partial view of each category and a single save button as follow
[image]

The existing code for it

```
    <md-dialog aria-label="Profile edit" class="profile-edit full-height">
      <form>
      <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
          <h2>Edit Profile</h2>
          <span flex></span>
          <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="hide()">
            <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-close" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
          </md-button>
        </div>
      </md-toolbar>


      <md-dialog-content >
        <md-tabs class=" margin-bottom-40" md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
            <md-tab label="Profile"> 
              <div layout layout-sm="column">
                <md-input-container flex="30">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container flex>
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName">
                </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <div layout layout-sm="column">
                <md-input-container flex="30">
                    <label>Other Name</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.otherName">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-select flex class="md-select-form" ng-model="user.gender" placeholder="Gender" ch-boolean>
                      <md-option ng-value="gender" ng-repeat="gender in ['Male', 'Female']">{{gender}}</md-option>
                </md-select>
                <md-input-container flex>
                      <label>Date of Birth</label>
                      <input type="date" ng-model="user.dateOfBirth">
                  </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <md-input-container>
                <label>Profile Picture</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" file-model = "user.myFile">
              </md-input-container> 

              <md-input-container flex>
                <label>Summary(max 200 characters)</label>
                <textarea ng-model="user.description" md-maxlength="200"></textarea>
              </md-input-container>      
            </md-tab>

            <md-tab label="Experience" ng-init="">
              <h2>Employment</h2>
              <div ng-repeat="experience in user.experiences"> 
                <md-input-container>
                    <label>Job title</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="experience.job_title">
                </md-input-container>
                <div layout layout-sm="column">
                  <md-input-container flex="66">
                      <label>Employeer Name </label>
                      <input type="text" ng-model="experience.company_name">
                  </md-input-container>
                  <md-input-container flex="33">
                      <label>Location</label>
                      <input type="text" ng-model="experience.location_name">
                  </md-input-container>
                </div>
                <div layout layout-sm="column">
                  <md-input-container flex="40">
                      <label>Start Date</label>
                      <input type="date" ng-model="experience.date_start" date-ob>
                  </md-input-container>
                  <md-input-container flex="40" ng-if="experience.current_work==0">
                      <label>End Date</label>
                      <input type="date" ng-model="experience.date_end" date-ob>
                  </md-input-container>
                  <md-checkbox flex ng-model="experience.current_work" ng-true-value='1' ng-false-value='0' aria-label="Current" style="margin: 5px;">
                    Current
                  </md-checkbox>
                </div>              
                  <md-input-container flex>
                    <label>Job Description </label>
                    <textarea ng-model="experience.job_des" ></textarea>
                  </md-input-container> 

              </div>
              <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="removeTab( tab )">Add Position</md-button>     
            </md-tab>

              <h2 class="md-subhead">Projects</h2>
              <div> 
                <md-input-container>
                    <label>Project Title</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.jobtitle">
                </md-input-container>
                <div layout layout-sm="column">
                  <md-input-container flex="66">
                      <label>Employeer Name </label>
                      <input type="text" ng-model="user.employeer">
                  </md-input-container>
                  <md-input-container flex>
                      <label>Start Date</label>
                      <input type="date" ng-model="user.startDate">
                  </md-input-container>
                  <md-input-container flex>
                      <label>End Date</label>
                      <input type="date" ng-model="user.endDate">
                  </md-input-container>
                </div>
                  <md-input-container flex>
                    <label>Project Details </label>
                    <textarea ng-model="user.jobDescription" ></textarea>
                  </md-input-container> 
              </div>
              <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="removeTab( tab )">Add Projects</md-button>     
            </md-tab>
              <div layout layout-sm="column">
                <md-input-container flex>
                    <label>Primary Number</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.primaryNumber">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container flex>
                    <label>Secondary Number</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.secondaryNumber">
                </md-input-container>
              </div>

              <div layout layout-sm="column">
                <md-input-container flex>
                    <label>Primary Email</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.primaryNumber">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container flex>
                    <label>Secondary Email</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.secondaryNumber">
                </md-input-container>
              </div>

              <h2 class="md-subhead">Social Media Links</h2>
              <md-input-container md-no-float>
                <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-facebook-squre" style="display:inline-block;"></md-icon>
                <input ng-model="user.address" type="text" placeholder="Url" >
              </md-input-container>
              <md-input-container md-no-float>
                <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-location-on" style="display:inline-block;"></md-icon>
                <input ng-model="user.address" type="text" placeholder="Url" >
              </md-input-container>
              <md-input-container md-no-float>
                <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-location-on" style="display:inline-block;"></md-icon>
                <input ng-model="user.address" type="text" placeholder="Url" >
              </md-input-container>
              <md-input-container md-no-float>
                <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-location-on" style="display:inline-block;"></md-icon>
                <input ng-model="user.address" type="text" placeholder="Url" >
              </md-input-container>



            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
      </md-dialog-content>

      <div class="md-actions" layout="row">
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button ng-click="hide()" class="md-primary">
         Cancel
        </md-button>
        <md-button ng-click="answer(this)" class="md-primary">
          Save
        </md-button>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </md-dialog>
```

In my controller i have coded to save the each tabs content as it is

```
$scope.answer = function(answer) {
    console.log(answer);
    Profile.editProfilePro($scope.user);
    Profile.editProfileExp($scope.user.experiences[0]);
    $mdDialog.hide(answer);
 };
```

I want to execute the Profile.editProfileExp($scope.user) only if current view in experience
The problem is how to save the current view tabs contents only in controller **answer()**?? Tell me your suggestions. Thanks .

Comment: use `Profile.editProfileExp($scope.experience);`

Comment: i need to execute only current editProfile . in this case either Profile.editProfileExp() or Profile.editProfilePro()

Answer (score 0):

you can have a scope variable as tabsdata for active tab, so that you can identify the selected Tab and add attribute "active="tabsdata.ExperienceTab" to you html "md-tab" tag it would provide you the active Tab status, and based on your selected tab execute your code.

Comment: "tabsdata" would be your scope variable so whenever you click tab due to 2 way binding its automatically update, no need to read active attribute, and if you would like to read  "active" attribute you can use jquery  yourHTMLElement.attr("active"). it will give you the value of active